# Celery current_task.update_state not working

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to add a long running async task and make it update it's progress status in intervals. I'm using a Django-rest-framework server, RabbitMQ broker, Celery worker. I'm able to add a task to celery, and even able to successfully retrieve the result upon task completion.

However whenever trying to get the state before task completion I get the following:

task.result = None, task.state = PENDING, task.info = None

When trying to get state post completion:

task.result = None, task.state = PENDING, task.info = None

```
DeployML/
    manage.py
    DeployML/
        ...
        settings.py
        tasks.py
        dcelery.py
        views.py
        urls.py
```

dcelery.py:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

import sys
sys.path.append('.....DeployML')
sys.path.append('.....DeployML/DeployML')
# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DeployML.settings')

app = Celery('DeployML', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', worker_state_db = '/tmp/celery_state')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

tasks.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DeployML.settings')
from celery import shared_task
from celery import current_task
from dcelery import app
import time

@app.task(bind=True)
def addShrd(self, x, y):
    for i in range(4):
        time.sleep(5)
        progress_percent = i
        #NOTE update_state not working yet
        current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': i, 'total': 4})
    return x + y
```

views.py:

```
#...
#...
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def celer_view(request):
    print("authentication: ", request.user, request.auth)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = addShrd.delay(17,10)
        return Response({'task_id': str(result.id)})    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({'some': 'POST response data'})    
    return Response({'some': 'data'})

from celery.result import AsyncResult
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def poll_state(request):
    data = 'Fail'
    print("requ: "+str(request.POST.get('task_id')))
    if 'task_id' in request.POST.keys() and request.POST['task_id']:
        task_id = request.POST['task_id']
        task = AsyncResult(task_id)
        print("meta data: "+ str(task.info))
        data = str(task.result) + " " +str(task.state) + " | " + str(task.info)
    else:
        data = 'No task_id in the request'
    return Response({'some': 'poll_state data: '+data})
```

EDIT:
I've updated views.py poll_state method to use celery.result.AsyncResult whereas earlier I was using dcelery.AsyncResult. However this hasn't resolved the issue.

EDIT2:
This issue is now resolved. I've found that there's a few seconds latency between executing update_state and AsyncResult being able to retrieve this. As my task was not long running(just 20 seconds) , before RabbitMQ could save the the intermediate progress, task was completed. However, If I increased task run time to say 100 seconds. I could see the intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

checkout  [Asyncresult](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult).

also check usages here: [celery.result.AsyncResult usages](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/59176/celery.result.AsyncResult)

Comment: Thanks @Suraj. This was one issue but one thing I figured out just now was there's a few seconds latency between executing update_state and AsyncResult being able to retrieve this. As my task was not long running(just 24 seconds) before I could see the intermediate progress task was completed. However, If I increased task run time to say 100 seconds. I could see the intermediate results.